# need to drop the rows in data frame based on the values which has in a separate list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

For Example
im having a data frame

```
col1   col2   col3

a      12      34

b      23      67

c      67      86
```

im having list

```
list=['b','f','r']
```

i need to remove the rows in the data frame which was there in the list

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried and what are the indexes of your rows? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Don't name lists `list` as it overrides a builtin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[~df["col1"].isin(lst)]
```

P.S. Please, avoid calling variables with python reserved words like `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
l = ['b','f','r']

df = pd.DataFrame(
         {'col1': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
          'col2': {0: 12, 1: 23, 2: 67},
          'col3': {0: 34, 1: 67, 2: 86}
            })
```

Now use the `.isin` method and negate it with a `~`

```
df[~df.col1.isin(l)]
```

Out:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    a    12    34
2    c    67    86
```